# matlab gui- use a button as a switch

Tags: image, matlab, user-interface, image-processing

I'm programming a robot that has a link to a matlab software.
It an image processing program.

I have programmed the most of the program, now I need to design the gui.
I need to do some sort of switch with the main program, as so:

when I push button 1- program starts run and data analysis.

when I push button 2- program stop running.

main function=> main(preImage) when preImage is a constant 640*480 image.

How can I do it?
Where do I need to set that loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
flag <- false

main()
{
  while(1)
  {
    while(flag)
    {
      //your code to analyze data
    }
  }
}

button1_clicked()
{
  flag <- true
}

button2_clicked()
{
  flag <- false
}
```